# yum installation failed on RHEL 7

Tags: linux, yum, rhel7

I tried to install telnet using yum with the following command:

```
yum install telnet
```

But I get the following error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLuQM.png)

How can I solve this and add third party repositories?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please use cut-and-paste for posting console output and format it as "`code`" rather than posting screenshots. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. - But do as suggested and check the contents of the epel yum repo configuration ...

Answer (score 0):

Please, register your RHEL version.

```
# subscription-manager register --username admin-example --password secret --auto-attach
```

Then validate repos.

To see a list of available repositories:

```
# subscription-manager repos --list
```

To enable a specific Red Hat repository:

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-6-server-optional-rpms
```

[**Enabling or disabling a repository using Red Hat Subscription Management**](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/265523)

As you desire add external repos please use the following command line:

```
# yum-config-manager --add-repo ***repository_url***
```

RHEL 7

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-*-optional-rpms \
                           --enable rhel-*-extras-rpms \
                           --enable rhel-ha-for-rhel-*-server-rpms
```

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```